# Get Eclipse Studio preferences

Tags: java, eclipse

Could not find a related question about whether there is an API that allows the retrieval of the IDE studio preferences from a simple class ex. Everything under Window-> Preferences. Another one-> how to extract everything under Preferences -> Network Connection.

The intented functionality will eventually be used in a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that will give you all the preferences, you have to look at individual preference pages.

Many preference pages use the Eclipse preferences API to store values in a 'preference node'. These can be accessed using two APIs:

```
IEclipsePreferences prefs = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("preference node id");

IPreferenceStore prefs = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "preference node id");
```

Both these APIs require you to know the 'preference node id' of the page, looking up individual preference values requires you to know the id of the individual preference. To find these you either need to look at the source code of the preference page or examine the 'xxx.prefs' file the Workspace '.metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings' folder.

Not all preference pages uses these APIs, the 'Network Connection' page you mention uses an internal API.